# Share an URL on facebook with GET parameters

Tags: facebook, url

I am trying to make a website url readable to Facebook but when I am try to copy and paste this url into the feed but looks like that Facebook is cleaning all values.

> website url

```
https://www.website.com/boat-rentals/search?city=Miami%20Beach&state=FL&country=Estados%20Unidos&latMapCenterValue=25.790654&lngMapCenterValue=-80.1300455&orderBy=1&searchBy=destinations&_all=Miami%20Beach,%20Flórida,%20EUA
```

> after pasted

```
https://www.website.com/boat-rentals/search?northeastlat=&northeastlon=&southwestlat=&southwestlon=&latMapCenterValue=&lngMapCenterValue=&city=&state=&country=
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely you have the wrong og:url set on the page. What is the real URL

Comment: @WizKid change website to boatsetter

Comment: Yes your page contains: <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.boatsetter.com/boat-rentals/search"> . Facebook follows og:url the same way as a redirect

Comment: @WizKid so in this case I should add all parameters on the content tag?

Comment: og:url should be the URL that you want to show up on Facebook.com. So yes